# Separate string in two parts: firts part is the title, the second is the chapter using php

Tags: php, string, variables, split, numbers

I've been trying for some time to figure out how to separate this string, but I can't figure it out... So, I have this string:

```
$book = "1Thessalonians 2";
```

Well, 1Thessalonians represents the chapter title and the number(2) after it represents the chapter. Is there any way to separate them so I can have two variables?
For example:

```
$title = "1Thessalonians";
$chapter = "2";
```

Comment: Can you give some more examples? Is there always a single number at the end? Without any spaces in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to build upon @Rabnawaz answer. I assume that the title can have spaces on its own. To solve this:

```
$splitStr = explode(" ", $book);
$title = "";
$chapter = "";
if(is_array($splitStr)){
 $chapter = $splitStr[count($splitStr) - 1]; // The last string
 unset($splitStr[count($splitStr) - 1]; // Remove the chapter from array
 $title = implode(" ", $splitStr); // Glue the string back together without the chapter
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$book = "1Thessalonians 2";

$split_str = explode(" ", $book);
$title =  $split_str[0];
$chapter =  $split_str[1];

echo $title;
echo $chapter;
```

the `explode` function split the string on the basis of space and return an array of string and then you can read array.